# js function can't see element inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I'm ng-repeat'ing out datepickers which uses [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) this requires a script in the page of the input like so:

```
<script>
$('[name="DOB"]').flatpickr({
    enableTime: false,
    dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
    minDate: new Date().fp_incr(-43800), // 120 years ago
    maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(-6570), // 18 years ago
});
```

This works fine when referencing input elements not inside an ng-repeat:

```
<input name="DOB" type="text"/>
```

But it does't work when this input is inside an ng-repeat, I've tried using ID+$Index and hardcoding it in the script to test, that doesn't work, and targeting it by name also doesn't work.

What do I need to do so the .flatpicker can see the element within the ng-repeat, I feel it might be a load order issue, with the inline script loading before the angular so theres no element initially for it to target.

I've tried placing the .flatpickr script in my AngularJS Controller but then all of angular fails to load in the browser with console error

> (...).flatpickr is not a function

Comment: Your angular code is running before the dom has finished rendering. More specifically, before ng-repeat has finished rendering it's items.

Comment: The datepicker script is at the bottom of the html file

Comment: `flatpickr is not a function` normally means you are not including the library or you include jQuery twice on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your script load before than ng-repeat.

1. Script files
2. ng-repeat elements.

You can try:

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('[name="DOB"]').flatpickr({
    enableTime: false,
    dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
    minDate: new Date().fp_incr(-43800), // 120 years ago
    maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(-6570), // 18 years ago
});  
},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wait for your view to be loaded in order to target the elements so that they are in the DOM.

If you use the `$viewContentLoaded` event listener in your mainController it will run every time the view has finished loading and then you can target the elements successfully.

Also if you want to use jQuery within your angular controller then you can use the `jQuery` keyword instead of $ and it should recognise it.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
   console.log('View has finished loading');
   //Firstly check if the DOB input field is in the DOM (as this function will run when any of our views have loaded so we need to make sure its the one we want.)
   let DOBInputField = document.getElementById('DOB');
   if(DOBInputField){
     //Therefore our DOB field is in the DOM so perform our JQuery
     jQuery('[name="DOB"]').flatpickr({
       enableTime: false,
       dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
       minDate: new Date().fp_incr(-43800), // 120 years ago
       maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(-6570), // 18 years ago
     });  
   }

 });
```

Note: You will need to add an id to your input field in order to target it with `document.getElementById` as I have done above

```
<input name="DOB" id="DOB" type="text"/>
```